# Импорт библиотеки в Python 3

Tags: python, ctypes

В одной книжке описан следующий участок кода и его результат[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from ctypes import *
msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string ="Hello world! \n"
msvcrt.printf("Test: %s",message_string)
```

У меня же при запуске данного скрипта выводится: "TPress any key to contuine..."(Visual studio 2017).
А в Python IDLE не выводится вообще ничего. В чём проблема и как её можно решить?

Comment: Запускайте через интерпретатор питона. А так, в консоль скрипт выведет `T`, а `Press any key to contuine...` VS2017 уже сама добавила

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`msvcrt.printf()` ждёт байтовую строку. Каковыми и являются по умолчанию строки в Python2. А вы запускаете скрипт в Python3, в котором по умолчанию юникод-строки. Исправить легко, достаточно добавить перед строками букву `b`:

```
from ctypes import *
msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = b"Hello world! \n"
msvcrt.printf(b"Test: %s", message_string)
```